# Adding a custom DateTimeField that can be updated through a PUT request (DjangoRestFramework)

Tags: android, python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and I created a django app by following this tutorial: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

This tutorial gives a pre-made User class that includes various fields. I am trying to add a custom DateTimeField that can be updated frequently through a PUT request in android. How would I add this custom field "timestamp" to this class.

**Here is my code:**

> Serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import models

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        lookup_field = 'username'
        set_timezone = 'date_joined'
        fields = ('url', 'username','date_joined')
```

> Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from tutorial.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
dir(settings)
settings.__dict__



class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

> Models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from datetime import datetime

class Time(models.Model):
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return "Time"
```

**ERROR**

> Exception Value:
>   Field name `timestamp` is not valid for model `User`.
>   Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in build_unknown_field, line 1079
>   Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Python Version: 2.7.6

Comment: Is `timestamp` just a custom field on your user model?

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, I am trying to create this custom DateTimeField called timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to `fields` in your serializer meta?

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, and I get an error, because I believe I need to create a view and model for it, but I'm uncertain about how to implement that.

Comment: Please include the error and your models in your question.

Comment: How does your time model connect to the user model?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use the `AbstractBaseUser` from Django in order to construct your own user model. This is more simple than creating a new dedicated `Time` model, and the DRF custom relational field that goes with it.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then, in your DRF serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        lookup_field = 'username'
        set_timezone = 'date_joined'
        fields = ('url', 'username','date_joined', 'timestamp')
```